# Create a sub-cube in SSAS Tabular

Tags: sql-server, ssas, mdx, tabular

I have an SSAS Tabular Cube, which I refresh daily. It's big and not efficient for some use-cases. I want to create a sub-cube with filtered data and deploy it as a separate cube. How should I do it?

One idea I have is to extract a sub-cube with MDX and store it in a new cube (and automate in SSIS Package). Is it possible? Can someone explain how to do it?

Comment: Big and not efficient are a bit vague descriptions. Do you have problems with processing times being too long? Do users feel that the cube is slow or the datamodel is too large? I wouldn't create a sub-cube by querying the original one, why not create smaller cobes based on the same queries as the big one, but filtered?

Comment: @Gigga, thanks for the feedback. Yes, it's exactly as you described - for some dive deep reports users feel that it's too slow. Also the model is too big as it tries to cover all use-cases. And you are absolutely right - I want to create a smaller cubes, but I also want to keep the main one, the big one. So I am looking for a scalable way to create a small cube out of the big one. And I ideally I would like to refresh the big one, and then just to copy the the subset of data into the small one instead of refreshing queries for the small one.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, that's a tricky spot.  Cubes aren't really designed to work so that you could create a subset out from another one. I mean, you can do that, but that's not what they are there for. You'd just have to create some DAX or MDX queries, which provides the data you need OR you can use M Query language to get the data.

If you'd like to use DAX, you can use SSIS Analysis Services Connector and Execute SQL -task for that purpose. If you don't have experience with DAX, you can use tools like Excel and import the data to a Power Pivot table. There you can drag and drop the fields you want and then get the underline DAX query with SQL Profiler (set up a pofiler session and click refresh in Excel to get the query).

For M Queries, it might be best to use Excel or Power BI Desktop and it's Power Query editor for designing the the output and then copy the M Query made by the editor. Then you can use the query and SSIS [Power Query Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/power-query-source?view=sql-server-ver15) to get the data.

If you have an Enterprise edition SQL Server, you might consider partitions to speed up the processing of the cube.

Another way would be to limit the amount of data to secondary cubes (only the current quarter / one country / one department / etc). I'm a fan of one cube one - one data area -type design. So I'd still suggest that you take a copy / multiple copies of your current cube project and make them be more specific to one specific area (for example in finance-cube, we might not need HR data).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I am familiar with DAX and MDX, and we have an Enterprise SQL Server and already have partitions. 
This is exactly what we want to do - to create a specific copy of an existing cube. I just want to understand how to do it in a scalable and automated way, so when I create a measure in the main cube it automatically deploys to the copy.

The main risk I see is that we have a copy and the main cube, and then they start to live their own lives. But what I want is that the copy is just a simplified version (with some filters and without some tables) of the main one.

Comment: I'm not aware that the changes in the cube structure can somehow in simple way be automatically copied to another cube. Again, that can be done, but that's not an easy task to achive. There are some tools to compare a cube to another and maybe those tools can be used here. I'm sorry that I don't have better answer here, I hope that someone else writes their opinion here as well.